# fread is incorrectly assigning info to dateResult

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, file-io, fread

```
            printf("please enter the day you wish search :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &day);
            printf("please enter the month you wish search :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &month);
            printf("please enter the year you wish search :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &year);
            for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                if (input[i].next.day == day & input[i].next.month == month & input[i].next.year == year)
                {
                    searchAmount = i;
                    fp = fopen("project.dat", "rb");
                    offset = searchAmount * sizeof(info);
                    fseek(fp, offset, 0);
                    fread(&dateResult[i], sizeof(info), 1, fp);
                    fclose(fp);
                    printf("\n%s\t%d", dateResult[i].deviceDescription, dateResult[i].serial);
                }
            }
```

when i use fread it automatically copies the next element of the array to dateResult opposed to following the variable i in the for loop.  essentially if i use more then one instance of the loop it doesnt take the next row of the array it take the column of the current row

Comment: The `&` operator performs a *bitwise* and.  You appear to want a *logical* and instead.  Use `&&` for that.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to use `i` for the `dateResult` index? Because not all iterations will have a search match which means there may be holes in the `dateResult`.

Comment: `if i use more then one instance of the loop` If that's what fails then post *that* code.

Comment: if amount is greater than 1 @dxiv

Comment: @RichardNoble The snippet you posted does nothing that "*automatically copies the next element of the array to dateResult*". If that's what happens, then the problem is elsewhere in the code that's missing. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).